# C-IDE with Sublime Text?

Tags: ide, sublimetext

Is there a good possibility to convert Sublime into a simple IDE that allows to edit, compile, link and run C prgograms. Without SublimeClang please, since this is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on Sublime's [build systems](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) and [`make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html). Both are very powerful tools, and allow for a lot of customization. You might need to do a bit of shell scripting to tie everything together into one command, but it's definitely possible, and not that hard, especially if you make good use of the [built-in variables](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#build-system-variables). The existing C++ system (available in `Packages/C++/C++.sublime-build`) should give you something to start with:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look for [bendras.co.uk blog post about Sublime Text 3 as C++ IDE by Paulius Zaliaduonis](http://www.bendras.co.uk/blog/2016-06-30%20Sublime%20Text%203%20as%20C++%20IDE). You will find more details how to do it.

Here is what you'll need:

- ctags
- gdb
- Sublime Text 3
- Sublime Text Package Control
- Sublime package CTags
- Sublime package SublimeGDB
- Your build system

All packages should work on most platforms: Windows, Linux, iOS?